# Combining RxJava 2 observables where some may never emit

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I'm working on a chat client which needs to combine data from two different Rx sources:

- A REST gateway which fetches an initial list of available chats and their messages: `Observable<List<Conversation>> getConversations()`
- A websocket gateway which emits new messages as they arrive: `Observable<Message> getMessages()`

Both observables should be combined in a single `Observable<ConversationsModel>` where ConversationsModel holds the conversation list and contains the logic to add messages to a given conversation.

The combined observable should emit the updated ConversationsModel every time either of the observables emits: on subscription the REST observable emits once and the websocket connection is established. Then, any new messages coming through the socket gateway should be added to the model, which is then re-emitted.

Here's my current solution which works, but I'm not happy with it since the ConversationsModel needs to be created outside the stream:

```
ConversationsModel conversations = new ConversationsModel();
conversationsObservable = restGateway.getConversations().map(list -> conversations.setConversations(list))
    .mergeWith(socketGateway.getMessages().map(message -> conversations.addMessage(message)))
    .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> socketGateway.connect())
    .doOnDispose(() -> socketGateway.disconnect())
    .replay(1)
    .refCount();
```

What I'm looking for is something rather like this:

```
conversationsObservable = restGateway.getConversations().map(list -> new ConversationsModel(list))
    .withLatestFrom(socketGateway.getMessages(), (conversationsModel, message) -> conversationsModel.addMessage(message))
    .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> socketGateway.connect())
    .doOnDispose(() -> socketGateway.disconnect())
    .replay(1)
    .refCount();
```

The problem is that `withLatestFrom` (as well as all other operators I've tried so far) does not emit anything until all observables have emitted at least once. In practice this means my UI will be blocked until the first message arrives through the socket connection, which is of course unacceptable.

Comment: Have you tried `combineLatest` and have some default values on the sources via `startWith()`?

Comment: I considered that but it seems like a hack. I'm rather looking for a "correct" solution to the problem.